# Debug second console application triggered by first console app in same solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have two console application projects in a single solution and they are both configured to build to a common directory.  The first app calls the second app via

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "myprocess.exe";
```

I can change my startup project and debug either one of them individually just fine, but I'm unable to step into the second project from the first project.  When I look in build\debug I see the .pdb files for both apps and I know the second app is running completely through its routines.  I just can't step into it.  I've looked at Attach to Process and Debug:Location but haven't been able to find a solution yet.  I've even tried putting them in different VS solutions, but to no avail.

So I need a way to step from the first project into the second project while debugging.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Debugger.Launch();
```

which will bring up the dialog asking if you want to attach a debugger.  You won't be able to 'step in' from the existing debugging session since it's attached to a different process.

Comment: Sam, thank you.  Do you mean add Debugger.Launch() in the second app that is being launched?

Comment: Sam,  thank you.  I added it to the second app and it worked great.  Thank you!